# Exporting protected PDF file in Kendo UI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, pdf-generation, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm currently using Kendo UI for Angular, and I was wondering if it is possible to export a protected PDF file (ex. password protected, and/or unprintable PDF file)?

Nothing is mentioned about it in the documentation. Is there a way to make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export a protected PDF is not possible please refer [this link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/export-pdf-with-password-security-or-encryption). You can ask it as a feature request [Here](https://www.telerik.com/support/feedback)